# Interface not updating until event

Tags: javascript, html

I started to make a simple game, but until i click on a button the UI doesn't update itself. i Did a function to update each second, (To add x value to a span) is possible to have it update by it self without user interaction every x time too? thanks

```js
function powerClick(number) {
  power = power + number;
  document.getElementById("powers").innerHTML = power;
};


window.setInterval(function() {
  powerClick(cursors);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: What is cursors? And your code would work if cursors contains a number

Comment: cursors is a variable, who will change over time as an "upgrade" who will simulate clicks over time with the setInterval and yes it work except the UI update that just update if i click again on the buttons the span is what i want to make it update without user clicking on it.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: http://prntscr.com/m45rrc here is a print of the code, its all working, just the UI im missing the auto update
here is the page it self
http://prntscr.com/m45shi

Comment: Please read [ask] and post a [mcve]